# How to run an array of function inside an array variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run series of functions i placed on a variable.

Here's a (**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fGaHR/5/)**)

**Code:**

```
function pass_me(x) {
    alert(x);        
};

var colors = new Array();
var colors = ["pass_me('yellow');", "pass_me('green');", "pass_me('blue');"]

for(var i = 0; i <= colors.length; i++) {
    window[colors[i]]();
}​
```

unfortunately, I can't make it run. Any idea what's wrong in my code?

Thanks

---

The story behind the array variable of function, is because i copied it from a dynamic element. This way it will only run what function is already in the page. So if pass_me("red") is not present, it will not be run.

Example:

```
<img src="img/something.jpg" ondblclick="pass_me("yellow")" />
<img src="img/something.jpg" ondblclick="pass_me("green")" />
<img src="img/something.jpg" ondblclick="pass_me("blue")" />
```

then I just use:

```
jQuery("td img").each(function(){
colors.push(jQuery(this).attr("ondblclick"));
})
```

Comment: for one, `"pass_me('yellow');"` is a string, you'll have to either eval it or parse it out.

Comment: The first `var colors` is unnecessary - it just gets overwritten when you create a new array on the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either change the array members to a handler like this:

```
function pass_me(x) {
    alert(x);        
};

var colors = [{ handler: pass_me, args: ['yellow'] }, { handler: pass_me, args: ['green'] }, { handler: pass_me, args: ['blue'] }];

for(var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    colors[i].handler.apply(this, colors[i].args);
};
```

This way you can have multiple handlers in the same array with different parameters per each handler.
Or initialize the members before calling them because data type of the members is string, not Function. like this:

```
function pass_me(x) {
    alert(x);        
};

var colors = ["pass_me('yellow')", "pass_me('green')", "pass_me('blue')"];

for(var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    eval(colors[i]);
};
```

Hope it helps you.

Cheers

Comment: I like the 2nd one using eval, but it seem it just run the first function and doesn't run the others. any idea?

Comment: this works like a charm. I changed eval(colors[i])(); - to -> eval(colors[i]);

Comment: **Both of your solutions are full of errors**, both syntactically and logically! -1 @Pennf0lio: You really should not accept incorrect answers.

Comment: @FelixKling It would be hard for me to determine which codes are semantic and which are not. I just selected Mohammad's answer as it addresses my problem and it works for me. I understand your concern that this community needs to have a quality codes and i have nothing against that :) thank you.

Comment: @Pennf0lio I should thank you and I'm sorry for the parantheses thing. I've just updated the post. Also I don't think that answer should alway work, an answer is something that motivates the questioner to the solution. When somebody asks "How can I write a Windows Service?" you'll never gonna write a full Windows Service Application for them, you just put them through the correct way and showing some helpful hint I think that would be enough. Nobody can say that I write codes with no error and exception. We all do mistakes that's our nature. Cheers

Comment: @MohammadGoudarzi it still has errors change `i <= colors.length` to `i < colors.length`, and also your first solution is totally wrong

Comment: Updated. Thank you for mentioning that. I was in hurry while answering. Why is that wrong?

Comment: This answer was a complete mess! I agree. I was in hurry while answering to go to work. Now I'm in office and I just saw what I did! Sorry guys and thank you everybody for helping. Cheers all.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. I removed my downvote. I agree that answers don't have to contain working code, but *if* they contain code, it should be at least syntactically correct (unless it's pseudo code).

Comment: Thank you dear @FelixKling. I do agree with you. Ofcourse. As I said, this one was a complete mess and I'm sorry for that. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a string of javascript, you would have to use eval to tell javascript to parse your string into javascript.  That is generally not the best way to write javascript.

To avoid using eval, I'd suggest this:

```
function pass_me(x) {
    alert(x);        
};

var colors = ["yellow", "green", "blue"];

for(var i = 0; i <= colors.length; i++) {
    pass_me(colors[i]);
}​
```

Or, if you really want to put the function in the array so you could have different functions in the array, you can do this:

```
function pass_me(x) {
    alert(x);        
};

var colors = [{fn:pass_me, color: "yellow"}, {fn:pass_me, color: "green"}, {fn:pass_me, color: "blue"}];

for(var i = 0; i <= colors.length; i++) {
    colors[i].fn(colors[i].color);
}​
```

Comment: I can't do this way because my approach in getting the variable was a little different. but thanks :)

Comment: @Pennf0lio - Then, clarify what your question really is, please.  There's no reason to embed javascript string function calls into an array when you could do it so many better ways.   You just haven't included enough info for us to know what ways are acceptable.

Comment: Apologize I didn't explain how i derive my variable. but now I just edited and added the details how i did it. What my approach was, I just copy the existing function being called from the "ondblclick" attribute of the image

Comment: The page is dynamic and it generates unique color each time, so the way to figure out what color is present on the page, I just copied what "pass_me('colors')" is already existing instead of running a functions with fix color values.

Comment: @Pennf0lio - well, we could have all helped in a much more directed way if you just showed the real problem in your original question, but it looks like you've now picked an answer already so I guess we're done now.

Comment: Yes, Sorry, It's my fault I skipped some details.

Answer (score 1):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fGaHR/8/)

```
function pass_me(x) {
    alert(x);        
}

var colors = ["yellow", "green", "blue"];

for(i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    pass_me(colors[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably safe to use `eval` here, but here is another solution, which I personally find a bit cleaner:

The event handlers are bound via HTML attributes. Most HTML attribute values are the basis for the corresponding DOM property value. In this case, each `img` DOM element has a property `ondblclick` with the function body being the value of the HTML attribute.

Meaning the HTML is equivalent to:

```
imgElement.ondblclick = function() {
    pass_me('yellow');
};
```

Hence, if you want to "collect" those functions, you just have to get a reference to the event handler:

```
var handlers = jQuery("td img").map(function(){
    return this.ondblclick;
}).get();
```

and call them later:

```
for(var i = 0, l = handlers.length; i < l; i++) {
    handlers[i]();
}
```

**However** if you just want to execute all the handlers without physically clicking on the images, you can just trigger an event on them:

```
jQuery("td img").trigger('dblclick');
```

This executes all event handlers for the `dbclick` event.

Comment: Yup, wow, thanks. this is more sophisticated approach compare to mine.

Answer (score 0):

you need to try

```
eval(colors[i]);
```

As it is a string not a function

Comment: yes this works, but it seem to just run the first function and not the others. 

http://jsfiddle.net/fGaHR/9/

Comment: @Pennf0lio try `eval(colors[i]);` instead of `eval(colors[i])();`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for anonymous functions:

```
function pass_me(x) {
    alert(x);        
}

var colors = [
    function(){ return pass_me('yellow'); }, 
    function(){ return pass_me('green'); },
    function(){ return pass_me('blue'); }
];

for(var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++){
    colors[i]();
}
```